# Closed and migrated questions not marked on interesting tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, interesting-page

When viewing the [interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) on the homepage, `[closed]` and `[migrated]` marks no longer appear on closed and migrated questions. This used to work correctly until a few days ago. Also, deleted questions are shown in the list with no indication that they were deleted.

For example, [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087142/equation-n-x2-y-x-y2) has been closed for over an hour, but still appears normally on the interesting tab (assuming you have the related tags marked as interesting), so I have to open the link before I can see that the question was closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow this has been broken for oh so long.

We had a long long standing bug with some of our caching constructs that we fixed last week. This bug meant the underlying issue was not noticed cause posts were not being cached properly.

So I went ahead and fixed the caching code to refresh this stuff properly (note: there is up to a 1 minute delay)

Additionally, there was a bug where view counts where never updating, I also fixed that.